# Certificate Error Accessing HTTPS by IP Address

Tags: ssl

So, I've gone through the process of ensuring the certificate has the IP address in the subject alternative name, but when I go to visit the site via IP, it says that name does not match the certificate.  The IP is obviously listed in the certificate and the CA Chain is trusted, but for some reason it continues to throw the warning.  I am still waiting for the DNS names to be created, so I cannot yet test if it has the error with the DNS name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory the IP address has to be listed in the SAN section as type IP, not DNS. In practice some broken applications require it the other way. Try to enter it as both IP and DNS to make it work in all cases.

> I am still waiting for the DNS names to be created, so I cannot yet test if it has the error with the DNS name.

Just add the relation between name and IP address to the local hosts file on the computer. Then you don't have to wait for propagation of DNS setups.

Comment: This is what I put in for the additional attributes:

san:dns=SERVER1.fakedomain.org&dns=SERVER1-A.fakedomain.org&dns=SERVER1-B.fakedomain.org&dns=SERVER1&ipaddress=10.0.0.1&ipaddress=10.0.0.2&ipaddress=10.0.0.3



This is the way we configured the other similiar device that works, so technically it should be ipaddress.
Edit: [link](https://i.imgur.com/G3FWbDC.png)

Comment: I went and created a new cert to include dns=name&dns=ip&ipaddress=ip and it works.  It's odd how the same hardware, just different firmware versions handle certificates differently.  The other one only has dns=name&ipaddress=ip and it works fine.   Oh well, as long as it works.

Comment: What kind of software/device is this? I'm always interested in broken SSL implementations.

Comment: It was Cisco UCSM running 2.2.3(d) on a pair of Cisco 6296 Fabric Interconnects.  One of our other UCS domains has the IP address listed under the ipaddress type and it worked fine.  That's what kind of threw me off.